# WPF Publish - include folders

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, deployment

I have a WPF project that is now finished, and I want to publish the app into an installer that other people can use.

When I publish the project, the project compiles into setup.exe, but on install the folders that I have do not get included.

[image: Image of my WPF installation]

I've been reading the guides, and made sure to include the files inside the folders as Content or a Resource. I've also made sure they are always copied. When some of my files are copied, they have a .deploy extension, and I need it to be an .xml in order for some function to read them. Images that I have in the app load fine however.

What do I need to do to have my custom files be EXACTlY as they are, xml as xml, txt as txt and so on. Also I have some empty folders, like this TempCF that I use at some point. Do i need to create it via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Project->Properties->Publish->Install Mode and Settings->Options->Deployment in Visual Studio, there is a "Use ".deploy" file extension" option that you can untick to get rid of the `.deploy` extension being added to your published files:

[image]

Empty project folders are not included in the output. Either put a dummy content file in them or create the folder dynamically as needed during runtime.

Comment: mm8 This solution will work, and it's more close to what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

@ Nikola L.

You could try to use the following methods to add the files in your program to the installation package so that you can have the files you need in your installation path. If I misunderstood your question, please let me know.

The steps are as follows:

1.Right-click on the **Setup** project and select View -> File System

2.In the File System page, right-click the **Application Folder** (File System on target Machine) and select **Add**->**Folder**(named User's Application Data ) -> **File…**-> find the file under your project and select the file you need.
Such as:
[image]
3.Right-click the Setup project.

4. Install your setup package.
5. You can find the files you added in your installation path.
   The result is like the picture below:
   [image]

Comment: This seems like a different type of publishing, right? This is not the built-in system, but rather an extension you can add to Visual Studio, right?